# Multi-steps register form in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

I'm building an app in which I've got a registration flow divided in 3 parts, Personal Info, Profile picture, and so on, each one in its invidual view. 
So, which way do you think is the best way to persist data between views so in the final step I can show the whole data to the user and ask for confirmation.

Local Storage? $cacheFactory? I've really have no idea how to do it, any advice will be usefull!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for an angular wizard 
if you are using ui-router, you can easily do this with nested states

have a look

http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router

> one form ( main state )
> separate templates (nested states)
>
> Note: specify controller for main state only and not for nested states

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I've wanted to do!

Answer (score 1):

cookie or local storage is available,but I think Angular way is recommended.

- $rootScope: you can storage user data in $rootScope simply use

  `$rootScope.userData = {
    'userName' : 'first',
    'userId' : 'second'
  };`

to storage and read data in new view, remember to inject $rootScope into your controller

- $broadcast: angular provide event $broadcast and $emit, so you can use $on to watch event and get your user data.and this is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/whitewolf/5JBA7/15/
- route resolve? : if you send user data in every step to database,
  you can use resolve in route config to load user data by $http.get().

add a service

```
app.factory("messageService", function($q){
    return {
      getMessage: function(){
         return $q.when("Hello World!");
     }};
});
```

in route config

```
$routeProvider
.when("/news", {
    templateUrl: "newsView.html",
    controller: "newsController",
    resolve: {
        message: function(messageService){
            return messageService.getMessage();
    }}
})
```

in your controller

```
app.controller("newsController", function (message) {
    $scope.message = message;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the requirement.

- If there is a requirement that the user can complete two steps and
  come back later to complete the third step, then better go with local
  persistence.
- But if it's really not the case, you need not use any persistence
  mechanism. Only thing is you need to properly map the models. And on the final submit, you can persist the complete input data.